# Is it possible to diable a button after it has been clicked 5 times?

Tags: javascript, html

After a user clicks the button five times, I want the button to become disabled.

Is it possible to just do in html, or would I need to use javascript?

Comment: It is indeed possible to get the indices of all values > 5. But in your case, there might be an alternative solution. Where do you change the array values? You could introduce a setter method that changes an array value at a given index and at the same time disables the respective button if value > 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can give every button a `data-clicks` attribute. which contains the number of clicks for this button.

Every time the user click any button check `data-clicks` attribute value if it equals 5. then disable the button. else just increase the number stored in `data-clicks`

**Example**

*You can only click 5 times for every button, after that the button will be disabled*

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".my-btn"), btn = null;

for (let i = 0;  i < btns.length; i += 1) {
    btns[i].onclick = function () {
    
        this.setAttribute('data-clicks', Number(this.getAttribute('data-clicks')) + 1)
        
        if (this.getAttribute('data-clicks') === '5') {
            this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="my-btn" value="button 1" data-clicks="0">
<input type="button" class="my-btn" value="button 2" data-clicks="0">
<input type="button" class="my-btn" value="button 3" data-clicks="0">
<input type="button" class="my-btn" value="button 4" data-clicks="0">
<input type="button" class="my-btn" value="button 5" data-clicks="0">
```

I removed the array because there is no need for it. also without it will work dynamically with your html buttons. you can easily remove or add buttons without any edits for your JavaScript code

**UPDATE**

for your jsfiddle you can embed my code in your `myno` function like this https://jsfiddle.net/bhoLbu8x/5/

Comment: Is this:   <div id="buttons"></div>   instead of buttons do i put 1, 2,3,4 because the buttons are auto created in this format <div id="1"></div> <div id="2"></div> ?

Comment: @raakobihai I updated it to take the index instead of the value. your rely is not clear for me.

Comment: OK so I have a code in js that creates a text field every time a person presses a button. There is nothing unique in the button label/name All the buttons are the same. But in the button id it increments from 1. so for example, <button class='arr' onclick='myon(1)' type='button' id='" 1 "'>Add a class</button> and so on. Every time a text field is created on the click of a button I want the vale of the corresponding placement of the array to increase. so  my button id = the placement in the array. Would this still work for that?

Comment: Can you share your code with us ? Update your question or put in https://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bhoLbu8x/1/ My actual question is the button named 'add a class', i do not want it to be clickable after 9 times. But each button needs to be separately counted for.

Comment: @Riz-waan the code updated. now you can click 4 times only for every single button. every button has its own counter.

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/bhoLbu8x/4/ trying to incorporate what you said. I am unsure why it is not working. Could you please take a look?

Comment: @Riz-waan updated!, your code works fine, you just need to move my code to your `myno` function

Answer (score 1):

Hope this gives you some idea:

```
var h = [2, 4, 6, 3, 4, 2, 7];
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var placementOfValueReaches5 = [];

h.forEach(function(value, index){
    if (value >= 5){
        button[index].setAttribute('disabled', true);
        placementOfValueReaches5.push(index);
    }
});

console.log(placementOfValueReaches5);  // outputs [2, 6]
```

More information of `Array.prototype.forEach` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp).

Comment: Does this also disable the button?

Comment: yes. the line `button[index].setAttribute('disabled', true)` disables the button.

Comment: your edit on the question completely changed the question and appropriate solution tho